# None rows when update dict given list of list of dicts for a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to build a Dataframe with a list of list of dict. 
Every dict has this structure:

```
object = {
    "id": 12345678,
    "attributes": {
         "name":...,
         "updatedAt": ...,
         "etc": ...
     }
}
```

and the list is like this:

```
[
 [object,object,object],
 [object,object,object],
 ...
]
```

I've just flatten the list and catching only the attributes using
`df = pd.DataFrame([r["attributes"] for s in list for r in s])`

but the problem comes when I want to add the "id" inside the attributes

I tried using:
`df = pd.DataFrame([r["attributes"].update({"id": r["id"]}) for s in snippet_list for r in s])`

But it returns me a Dataframe with empty data:

```
        0
0     None
1     None
2     None
3     None
4     None
5     None
6     None
7     None
8     None
9     None
10    None
11    None
12    None
13    None
14    None
15    None
16    None
17    None
18    None
19    None
20    None
21    None
22    None
23    None
24    None
25    None
26    None
27    None
28    None
29    None
```

Expected output:

```
        id    name   updatedAt
0     1234  cabesa  2019-06-20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` is a mutator that returns `None`.  Try `{"id": r["id"], **r["attributes"]}` instead to unpack the attributes dictionary.